# Largest interval of a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, interval-arithmetic

I was able to find the general solution of the given differential equation:
$ \frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{cos(x)}{sin(x)}y = \frac{1}{cos^2(x)sin(x)}$.

The general solution is **y = sec(x) + csc(x)C.**

Now I don't get it how to find the largest interval(interval of validity). All I know are sec(x)= 1/cos(x) is undefined if cos(x) is equal to 0, that is, the value $ \frac{\pi}{2} + \pi n $ for all integers n, and csc(x)=1/sin(x) is undefined if sin(x) is equal to 0, that is, the value $\pi n$ for all integers n.

Comment: Do you have an initial condition? Without that it would be difficult to determine the correct interval. What do you know about linear DE and maximal solutions?

Comment: There is no initial condition. I just know the basics of linear DE(such as knowing if it is homogenous or nonhomogenous, then solving it) and maximal solutions.

Comment: I am also thinking if p(x) = cos(x)/sin(x) and Integrating factor is ln|sinx|) then it has an interval of (-inf,0)or(pi,inf). Am I wrong with that? ;_; I'm lost help.

Answer (score 1):

If you multiply with $\sin x$, you get the integrable equation
$$
(\sin(x)y(x))'=\frac1{\cos^2x}\implies \sin(x)y(x)=\tan(x)+C
$$
which gives directly the cited solution.

You have correctly identified the singularities of that solution formula. An ODE solution has its domain restricted such that the function is continuously differentiable over this domain. This means that the available domains are $(k\frac\pi2,(k+1)\frac\pi2)$, $k\in\Bbb Z$. The exact domain depends on where the initial point is given.

---

It is in general true that solutions for
$$
y^{(n)}(x)+a_{n-1}(x)y^{(n-1)}(x)+...+a_1(x)y'(x)+a_0(x)y(x)=r(x)
$$
have as maximal domain the maximal open interval that contains the initial time or position and such that all coefficients $a_k(x)$ and the right side $r(x)$ are continuous over this interval.

Comment: So if k = 0, the largest interval would be (0, pi/2). Then that's just an interval for a particular solution given an initial condition?